# jquery traversal next sibling on click

Tags: jquery, dom

Im having trouble traversing this particular DOM tree with jQuery.

On click of the `.heading` lable I'd like to act on the `.group` sibiling. The goal is to create functionality that works much like an accorion, on click the element reacts one way, while all the others act another.

Here is the markup:

```
<lable class="heading">1</lable>
<div class="group">
    <div class="input">
        <lable>inner</lable>
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<lable class="heading">2</lable>
<div class="group">
    <div class="input">
        <lable>inner</lable>
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
<lable class="heading">3</lable>
<div class="group">
    <div class="input">
        <lable>inner</lable>
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the jQuery I've so far:

```
$('.heading ').click(function () {
    $('.heading').not(this).each(function () {
       $(this).css('background','blue');
    });
    $(this).css('background','none');
});
```

Im able to grab the element clicked but not the next sibling. Can someone give me a pointer?

here is a jfiddle that does what I want (but on the wrong elements):
[http://jsfiddle.net/orionrush/MDX2x/](http://jsfiddle.net/orionrush/MDX2x/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.next()` method, note that you don't need the `.each()` method, most of the jQuery methods call `.each()` behind the scene.

```
$('.heading').on('click', function() {
    $('.heading').not(this).next('.group').css('background','none');
    $(this).next().css('background','blue');
});
```

You can also use a `class` instead of setting inline `css`:

```
$('.heading').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.group') // next .group sibling
           .addClass('active')
           .siblings('.group') // .group siblings of the selected .group element
           .removeClass('active');
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Comment: Thanks so much. Agreed regarding addClass. My intent however isn't to style, I was just using css as a proof and for brevity as I have more complex interactions in mind.